# Android - Show progress dialogue while waiting for imageview from a URL

Tags: java, android, url, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am loading an image view from a URL and want a progress dialogue to show while waiting for the image to load, when I run the app, the porgress dialogue appears for like half a second then disappears and has nothing to to with the status of the image. How can I make it so that the progress dialogue disappears only once the image is loaded?

below is my code

```
//below is the download image task****************************************

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
      ImageView bmImage;

      public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
          this.bmImage = bmImage;
      }

      protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String urldisplay = urls[0];
          Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
          try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return mIcon11;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
          bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
      }
    }

// above is the download imagetask ****************************************************

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
      private ProgressDialog progress;

    public MyTask(ProgressDialog progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
      }

      public void onPreExecute() {
        progress.show();
      }

      public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

          progress.dismiss();
      }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivget))
            .execute("http://dieboltdesigns.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/tom-brady-beast-poster-copy.png");

    //above makes the progress bar
        return null;
    }
    }
```

if you need the doinbackgound method/asynctask let me know in comments

Thanks

Comment: have you got result from url.?

Comment: @Segi if you are asking if the image loads the answer is yes

Comment: Always populate the UI in postexecute method..

Comment: where you are setting your image which you are downloading form URL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have used `AsyncTask` inside `AsyncTask` if I am not wrong. `DownloadImageTask` is another Thread which is independent of current one. That is the problem.

Just write down all the code of `DownloadImageTask` in `MyTask`.

**Edit**

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
  ImageView bmImage;
  ProgressDialog pd;
  Context mContext;

  public DownloadImageTask(Context context,ImageView bmImage) {
      this.bmImage = bmImage;
      mContext = context;
  }

  public void onPreExecute() {
      pd = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "dialog title","dialog message", true);   
  } 

  public void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
      pd.dismiss();
      if(result!=null)
          bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
  }

  protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String urldisplay = urls[0];
      Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
      try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return mIcon11;
  }
}
```

Comment: I posted my download asynctask, do you think you could merge them and repost it for me ?

Comment: Just paste showing dialog in `DownloadImageTask` instead of `MyTask`. This will be fine. Remove any one what you like. Just don't use `Async` inside `Async`.

Comment: :D Now I have to say something..... what is different from mine? You answered to write code into MyTask and you edited with another :D

Comment: @PankajKumar, :-)... I have no problem my friend. But all are not like you and mine. When I gave answer to some question before 3-4 days, one another guy just give me such reply though my answer is just 45 secs difference in post. That is why I wrote here. Pardon if hurt. I am removing my comment there.

Comment: @ChintanRathod thanks, where do you define the result variable ?

Comment: No problem I have. Just chill and enjoy... SO points are not our life and knowledge. Your points are less than mine... but its doesn't mean that you know less than me. Right? So just enjoy here. I am removing my answer because your deserves accept.

Comment: @ChintanRathod THANKS! as soon as I have 15 rep I will upvote this

Comment: @ChintanRathod just out of curiosity, where did you learn how to get so good at android, buy a book, watch youtube tutorials?

Comment: @user222786, I don't know really that I am good at android. :-P. Due to forum and having 1 year spending in Android live application development, may this add such knowledge to me. I try myself to post articles, learn new things from different sites.